# Illustrator CS5: Selection Tool Highlights Object Just by Passing Over It?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, tools, selections

This isn't a major issue, but I recently reset my preferences for Illustrator CS5 and now find the Selection Tool (black arrow) is highlighting every single object I pass over. Previously, only once I clicked on an object or text would a bounding box appear. But now whenever I pass my cursor over shapes it highlights the outside path, and when I pass my cursor over text a gray box appears. Here's a screenshot of the gray box issue.

[image]

I just want to turn off this setting or reset a preference that was changed. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely due to Smart Guides being on.

`View > Smart Guides` (unless it's in a different place for CS5, which is possible).